# Hadoop run WordCount Failed

Tags: java, hadoop

I tried to run WordCount in terminal with command

```
hadoop jar ~/Study/Hadoop/Jars/WordCount.jar \
WordCount /input/input_wordcount/ /output
```

but it failed with the following error:

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are  you running on vmware  !  close the fire wall at fisrt  !
try   `service iptables stop`  or `chkconfig iptables off`

add this configuration  in `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
```